# Separator after each div, except the last

Tags: html, css

Between each article, I have a horizontal separator:

```css
.article {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="articles">
  <div class="article">Hello1</div>
  <div class="article">Hello2</div>
  <div class="article">Hello3</div>
  <div class="article">Hello4</div>
</div>
```

How to remove, with CSS, the useless horizontal line after the last child of `#articles`? (useless because there is no next article, so no separation needed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With this CSS:

```
.article:last-child { border-bottom: none; }
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/r8pbLaas/

Answer (score 5):

Use `:last-child` pseudo selector:

```
.article:last-child { border-bottom: none; }
```

Basically, what this selector does is ask the question "*Am I the last direct child element of my parent?*", and if so, applies the rules.

**Note:** `:last-child`, as well as `:first-child`, are often misinterpreted by CSS beginners. It does **not** mean "*find my last child element*".

```css
.article { margin-bottom: 20px; padding-bottom:20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE; }
.article:last-child {
   border-bottom: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<div id="articles">
  <div class="article">Hello1</div>
  <div class="article">Hello2</div>
  <div class="article">Hello3</div>
  <div class="article">Hello4</div>
</div>
```

Find more information on it here:

> https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/

Answer (score 3):

Something like this

```css
.article:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="articles">
    <div class="article">Hello1</div>
    <div class="article">Hello2</div>
    <div class="article">Hello3</div>
    <div class="article">Hello4</div>
</div>
```

OR

```css
 .article {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
 }
 .article:last-child {
   border-bottom:0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="articles">
  <div class="article">Hello1</div>
  <div class="article">Hello2</div>
  <div class="article">Hello3</div>
  <div class="article">Hello4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's noteworthy that support for `:last-child` is much better than for `:not`, so if IE < 9 is relevant (and IE 8 is still quite common), `:last-child` is way to go. What I like about your first solution, though, is that is does not require resetting useless property settings.

Comment: @connexo ty, I didn't know that `:not` was not supported by IE < 9

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `:first-child` instead `:last-child` because **IE7+** supports it ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/j1td0xkk/)):

```css
.article { 
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

    .article:first-child {
        padding-top: 0;
        border-top: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="articles">
    <div class="article">Hello1</div>
    <div class="article">Hello2</div>
    <div class="article">Hello3</div>
    <div class="article">Hello4</div>
</div>
```

See browsers support of [:first-child](http://caniuse.com/#search=first-child) vs [:last-child](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few of other solutions to this problem that are worth a mention.

**:first-child**

You can use `:first-child` along with setting your border on the top of teach element - first child then removes the border on the first element and the visual output is the same.

As `:first-child` is in the css2 spec you can count on wider browser support than `:last-child`. This is an edge case for sure, but one that could conceivably be hit, especially considering the browsers in question are IEs.

It's also [easier to compute](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors) in the browser than last child. The browser doesn't have to do anything to look at all the elements and work out the last, it can just stop at the first that matches. Worth considering if your front end is complex.

**Adjacent selectors**

Adjacent selector rules allow you to target an element only if it has another element of the specified type as a sibling. So:

```
p + p { border-top: 1px solid #888; }
```

will set a border top on a `p` tag only if it's preceded by a `p` tag.

Again this will cover edge case browsers that :last-child might not though I think it's cited as a performance concern, suffering somewhat similar issues to :last-child.

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

**A class**

You can also just use a class on the last element. While this isn't necessary visually for this problem it's worth considering if you want to do more complex things with the last element, or if the containing HTML may change for some reason.

Comment: I like your approach of showing alternatives; it has to be noted, though, that `p + p` does not target a "p followed by another p" - as you said, but a "p that is following a p". To make it clearer, `div + p` targets the `p`, not the `div` (as you claimed).

Answer (score 2):

```
.article:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Comment: `:not` is not supported in IE < 9.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.article:last-child { border-bottom: none; }`
Each other `.article` element will have the defined style(/the border)!